# iPhone Image Processing with Accelerate Framework and vDSP

Tags: iphone, image-processing, accelerate-framework, vdsp

UPDATE: Please see additional question below with more code;

I am trying to code a category for blurring an image. My starting point is [Jeff LaMarche's sample here](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/08/uiimage-blur.html). Whilst this (after the fixes suggested by others) works fine, it is an order of magnitude too slow for my requirements - on a 3GS it takes maybe 3 seconds to do a decent blur and I'd like to get this down to under 0.5 sec for a full screen (faster is better).

He mentions the Accelerate framework as a performance enhancement so I've spent the last day looking at this, and in particular vDSP_f3x3 which according to the Apple Documenation

> Filters an image by performing a
>   two-dimensional convolution with a 3x3
>   kernel; single precision.

Perfect - I have a suitable filter matrix, and I have an image ... but this is where I get stumped.

vDSP_f3x3 assumes image data is (float *) but my image comes from;

```
srcData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData (context);
```

and the context comes from CGBitmapContextCreate with kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst, so my srcData is really ARGB with 8 bits per component.

I suspect what I really need is a context with float components, but [according to the Quartz documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html), kCGBitMapFloatComponents is only available on Mac OS and not iOS :-(

Is there a really fast way using the accelerate framework of converting the integer components I have into the float components that vDSP_f3x3 needs? I mean I could do it myself, but by the time I do that, then the convolution, and then convert back, I suspect I'll have made it even slower than it is now since I might as well convolve as I go.

Maybe I have the wrong approach?

Does anyone have some tips for me having done some image processing on the iphone using vDSP? The documentation I can find is very reference orientated and not very newbie friendly when it comes to this sort of thing.

If anyone has a reference for really fast blurring (and high quality, not the reduce resolution and then rescale stuff I've seen and looks pants) that would be fab!

EDIT:

Thanks @Jason. I've done this and it is almost working, but now my problem is that although the image does blur, on every invocation it shifts left 1 pixel. It also seems to make the image black and white, but that could be something else.

Is there anything in this code that leaps out as obviously incorrect? I haven't optimised it yet and it's a bit rough, but hopefully the convolution code is clear enough.

```
CGImageRef CreateCGImageByBlurringImage(CGImageRef inImage, NSUInteger pixelRadius, NSUInteger gaussFactor)
{
unsigned char *srcData, *finalData;

CGContextRef context = CreateARGBBitmapContext(inImage);
if (context == NULL) 
    return NULL;

size_t width = CGBitmapContextGetWidth(context);
size_t height = CGBitmapContextGetHeight(context);
size_t bpr = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);

int componentsPerPixel = 4; // ARGB

CGRect rect = {{0,0},{width,height}}; 
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, inImage); 

// Now we can get a pointer to the image data associated with the bitmap
// context.

srcData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData (context);

if (srcData != NULL)
{

    size_t dataSize = bpr * height;
    finalData = malloc(dataSize);
    memcpy(finalData, srcData, dataSize);

    //Generate Gaussian kernel

    float *kernel;  

    // Limit the pixelRadius

    pixelRadius = MIN(MAX(1,pixelRadius), 248);
    int kernelSize = pixelRadius * 2 + 1;

    kernel = malloc(kernelSize * sizeof *kernel);

    int gauss_sum =0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelRadius; i++)
    {
        kernel[i] = 1 + (gaussFactor*i);
        kernel[kernelSize - (i + 1)] = 1 + (gaussFactor * i);
        gauss_sum += (kernel[i] + kernel[kernelSize - (i + 1)]);
    }

    kernel[(kernelSize - 1)/2] = 1 + (gaussFactor*pixelRadius);

    gauss_sum += kernel[(kernelSize-1)/2];

    // Scale the kernel

    for (int i=0; i<kernelSize; ++i) {
        kernel[i] = kernel[i]/gauss_sum;
    }

    float * srcAsFloat,* resultAsFloat;

    srcAsFloat = malloc(width*height*sizeof(float)*componentsPerPixel);
    resultAsFloat = malloc(width*height*sizeof(float)*componentsPerPixel);

   // Convert uint source ARGB to floats

    vDSP_vfltu8(srcData,1,srcAsFloat,1,width*height*componentsPerPixel);

    // Convolve (hence the -1) with the kernel

    vDSP_conv(srcAsFloat, 1, &kernel[kernelSize-1],-1, resultAsFloat, 1, width*height*componentsPerPixel, kernelSize);

    // Copy the floats back to ints

    vDSP_vfixu8(resultAsFloat, 1, finalData, 1, width*height*componentsPerPixel);

    free(resultAsFloat);
    free(srcAsFloat);

}

size_t bitmapByteCount = bpr * height;

CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, finalData, bitmapByteCount, &providerRelease);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerComponent(context),
                                   CGBitmapContextGetBitsPerPixel(context), CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context), CGBitmapContextGetColorSpace(context), CGBitmapContextGetBitmapInfo(context), 
                                   dataProvider, NULL, true, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);

CGDataProviderRelease(dataProvider);
CGContextRelease(context); 


return cgImage;
}
```

I should add that if I comment out the vDSP_conv line, and change the line following to;

```
       vDSP_vfixu8(srcAsFloat, 1, finalData, 1, width*height*componentsPerPixel);
```

Then as expected, my result is a clone of the original source. In colour and not shifted left. This implies to me that it IS the convolution that is going wrong, but I can't see where :-(

THOUGHT: Actually thinking about this, it seems to me that the convolve needs to know the input pixels are in ARGB format as otherwise the convolution will be multiplying the values together with no knowledge about their meaning (ie it will multiple R * B etc). This would explain why I get a B&W result I think, but not the shift. Again, I think there might need to be more to it than my naive version here ...

FINAL THOUGHT: I think the shifting left is a natural result of the filter and I need to look at the image dimensions and possibly pad it out ... so I think the code is actually working OK given what I've fed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely want to convert to `float` to perform the filtering since that is what the accelerated functions take, plus it is a lot more flexible if you want to do any additional processing.  The computation time of a 2-D convolution (filter) will most likely dwarf any time spent in conversion.  Take a look at the function `vDSP_vfltu8()` which will quickly convert the uint8 data to float.  `vDSP_vfixu8()` will convert it back to uint8.

To perform a blur, you are probably going to want a bigger convolution kernel than 3x3 so I would suggest using the function `vDSP_imgfir()` which will take any kernel size.

**Response to edit:**

A few things:

1. You need to perform the filtering on each color channel independently.  That is, you need to split the R, G, and B components into their own images (of type float), filter them, then remultiplex them into the ARGB image.
2. `vDSP_conv` computes a 1-D convolution, but to blur an image, you really need a 2-D convolution.  `vDSP_imgfir` essentially computes the 2-D convolution.  For this you will need a 2-D kernel as well.  You can look up the formula for a 2-D Gaussian function to produce the kernel.
   **Note:** You actually can perform a 2-D convolution using 1-D convolutions if your kernel is seperable (which Gaussian is).  I won't go into what that means, but you essentially have to perform 1-D convolution across the columns and then perform 1-D convolution across the resulting rows.  I would not go this route unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks @Jason, I've nearly got it working now thanks to those hints, although I'm using vDSP_conv rather than vDSP_imgfir. Can you see anything obviously wrong with my code with the changes?

Comment: @Roger, see my response above

Comment: many thanks again. That all makes sense ... I'll tackle the demux stuff tomorrow and see how I get on.

Comment: Thanks. This helps. I didn't knew vDSP_conv only did 1D convolutions. But could have used `vImageConvolve_ARGB8888` as in @IanOllman anwer

Comment: Yeah, vImageConvolve_ARGB8888 is a better option, but that wasn't available back in May 2011 when this question was asked.  It was added in iOS 5 (October 2011).

Answer (score 12):

While the Accelerate framework will be faster than simple serial code, you'll probably never see the greatest performance by blurring an image using it.

My suggestion would be to use an OpenGL ES 2.0 shader (for devices that support this API) to do a two-pass box blur.  Based on my benchmarks, the GPU can handle these kinds of image manipulation operations at 14-28X the speed of the CPU on an iPhone 4, versus the maybe 4.5X that Apple reports for the Accelerate framework in the best cases.

Some code for this is described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355525/opengl-es-2-0-fragment-shader-to-blur-is-slow-and-low-quality), as well as in the "Post-Processing Effects on Mobile Devices" chapter in the [GPU Pro 2 book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568817185) (for which the sample code can be found [here](http://downloads.akpeters.com/gpupro/)).  By placing your image in a texture, then reading values in between pixels, bilinear filtering on the GPU gives you some blurring for free, which can then be combined with a few fast lookups and averaging operations.

<strike>If you need a starting project to feed images into the GPU for processing, you might be able to use my sample application from the article [here](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios).  That sample application passes AVFoundation video frames as textures into a processing shader, but you can modify it to send in your particular image data and run your blur operation.  You should be able to use my `glReadPixels()` code to then retrieve the blurred image for later use.</strike>

Since I originally wrote this answer, I've created [an open source image and video processing framework](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) for doing these kinds of operations on the GPU. The framework has several different blur types within it, all of which can be applied very quickly to images or live video. The GPUImageGaussianBlurFilter, which applies a standard 9-hit Gaussian blur, runs in 16 ms for a 640x480 frame of video on the iPhone 4. The GPUImageFastBlurFilter is a modified 9-hit Gaussian blur that uses hardware filtering, and it runs in 2.0 ms for that same video frame. Likewise, there's a GPUImageBoxBlurFilter that uses a 5-pixel box and runs in 1.9 ms for the same image on the same hardware. I also have median and bilateral blur filters, although they need a little performance tuning.

In my benchmarks, Accelerate doesn't come close to these kinds of speeds, especially when it comes to filtering live video.

Comment: This is a really interesting idea ... thanks for the lateral thinking. I hadn't appreciated that I could use openGLES for image processing within a non openGL project so that opens up a lot of ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

So answering my own question with Jason's excellent help, the final working code fragment is provided here for reference in case it helps anyone else. As you can see, the strategy is to split the source ARGB (I'm ignoring A for performance and assuming the data is XRGB) into 3 float arrays, apply the filter and then re-multiplex the result.

It works a treat - but it is achingly slow. I'm using a large kernel of 16x16 to get a heavy blur and on my 3GS it takes about 5 seconds for a full screen image so that's not going to be a viable solution.

Next step is to look at alternatives ... but thanks for getting me up and running.

```
    vDSP_vfltu8(srcData+1,4,srcAsFloatR,1,pixels);
    vDSP_vfltu8(srcData+2,4,srcAsFloatG,1,pixels);
    vDSP_vfltu8(srcData+3,4,srcAsFloatB,1,pixels);

    // Now apply the filter to each of the components. For a gaussian blur with a 16x16 kernel
    // this turns out to be really slow!

    vDSP_imgfir (srcAsFloatR, height, width, kernel,resultAsFloatR, frows, fcols);
    vDSP_imgfir (srcAsFloatG, height, width, kernel,resultAsFloatG, frows, fcols);
    vDSP_imgfir (srcAsFloatB, height, width, kernel,resultAsFloatB, frows, fcols);

    // Now re-multiplex the final image from the processed float data

    vDSP_vfixu8(resultAsFloatR, 1, finalData+1, 4, pixels);
    vDSP_vfixu8(resultAsFloatG, 1, finalData+2, 4, pixels);
    vDSP_vfixu8(resultAsFloatB, 1, finalData+3, 4, pixels);
```

Answer (score 3):

For future reference if you're considering implementing this **DON'T: I've done it for you!**

see: 
https://github.com/gdawg/uiimage-dsp

for a UIImage Category which adds Gaussian/Box Blur/Sharpen using vDSP and the Accelerate framework.

Comment: Excellent - I have no intention of re-inventing any wheels and will be delighted to make use of your library which at first look seems absolutely perfect - many thanks for drawing my attention to it.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using vDSP to do image filtering?  Try vImageConvolve_ARGB8888(). vImage is the image processing component of Accelerate.framework.